# DjangoRestFramework - has_permission incorrectly overriding has_object_permission

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

This is my permission:

```
class IsCreationOrAuthenticatedOrIsOwnerOrWatchOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Allow only the owner (and admin) of the object to make changes (i.e.
    do PUT, PATCH, DELETE and POST requests. Allow all other users
    ReadOnly or Follow options. This is for UserViewSet. Allow unauthenticated users to
    create objects.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            if view.action == 'create':
                return True
            return False

        return request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS or request.user.is_staff or view.action=='follow'

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return False

        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        if request.user.is_staff:
            return True

        if view.action == 'follow':
            return True

        return obj.owner == request.user
```

The problem is that authenticated users cannot PUT, PATCH or DELETE their own account because in `has_permission` it says:

```
return request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS or request.user.is_staff or view.action=='follow'
```

However, PUT, PATCH and DELETE here depends on if `obj.owner == request.user` (it depends on the object). So how do I allow users to PUT, PATCH and DELETE only their account when `has_permission` does not have access to object and therefore shouldn't allow any PUT, PATCH and DELETE (because it all depends whether or not the `obj.owner == request.user`.

Comment: Why don't you remove the checks from `has_permission` and allow the unsafe methods? They will be checked in `has_object_permission` anyway.

Comment: @RetoAebersold Because creating objects and getting a list of objects is not handled by `has_object_permission`, it's handled by `has_permission`. And I need to make sure unauthenticated users cannot GET a list of objects  but have access to POST (creating objects).

Comment: For anyone else with this problem, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533277/django-rest-framework-restrict-user-data-view-to-admins-the-very-own-user)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you disable `has_permissions` and modify `has_object_permission` to check for POST as well?

```
def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        return True

    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return False

    if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        return True

    if request.user.is_staff:
        return True

    if view.action == 'follow':
        return True

    return obj.owner == request.user
```