# Django Rest Framework restrict user data view to admins & the very own user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django and DRF, and I would like to check if a user (regular one), after it has been authenticated, is allowed to view it's own profile and only that (no other user's).

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'url', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'groups', 'is_staff')

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = super().create(validated_data)
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user
```

**Views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
"""
queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
serializer_class = UserSerializer
permission_classes = (IsUser,)
```

**permissions.py**

```
class IsUser(permissions.BasePermission):
"""
Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
"""

def has_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    # View or Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the snippet.
    return obj.owner == request.user
```

This, obviously is not working, because is wrong. But I can not figure out how to allow a user to view:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/7

ONLY if its an admin, or the very same user doing the request.

And:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/
Only if it's an admin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            self.permission_classes = [IsSuperUser, ]
        elif self.action == 'retrieve':
            self.permission_classes = [IsOwner]
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_permissions()

class IsSuperUser(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_superuser

class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user:
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                return True
            else:
                return obj.owner == request.user
        else:
            return False
```

override list and retrieve method for UserViewSet probably the easiest way.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies in advanced as I don't have enough rep to add to Ykh's answer

`views.py`

```py
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        # Overrides to tightest security: Only superuser can create, update, partial update, destroy, list
        self.permission_classes = [IsSuperUser]

        # Allow only by explicit exception
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            self.permission_classes = [IsOwner]

        return super().get_permissions()
```

`permissions.py`

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class IsSuperUser(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_superuser


class IsOwner(BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user:
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                return True
            else:
                return obj.owner == request.user
        else:
            return False
```

Note: `obj.owner` otherwise you will always be denied if you are not a superuser.

Thank you Ykh for the base answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a additional check in `IsUser` permission .

```
if request.method == permissions.SAFE_METHOD:
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

like sample, list for default-auth, edit only for superuser

```py
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser


class CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):
    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        return  # To not perform the csrf check previously happening


class OnlyListAvaliableMixin:
    authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication,)

    def get_permissions(self):
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] if self.action == 'list' else [IsAdminUser] # noqa
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]


# Example to use
class ListView(OnlyListAvaliableMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet, ):
    # premission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    queryset = CarMark.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListViewSerializer
```